# Number of input file incorrect when using Internet explorer 6.0

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this jquery button click function:

```
   $("#NextButton_ButtonCtrl").live("click", function (event) {

    var i = 0;
    var success = 1;
    var n = $("input[type=File]").length;
    alert('number of files:' + n);

    $("input[type=File]").each(function () {

        success = 0;
        alert('for is here');
        /*var labelId = "FondationLabel" + i + "_LabelCtrl";
        var intitule = $("span[id=" + labelId + "]").text();
        var style = $(this).attr('style');
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == "" && style == "True") {
        success = 0;

        $("#errorSpan").html('<span ID=errorSpan class=error-span >Merci de charger le fichier' + intitule + '</span>');
        //var MPE = $find("MPE");
        // MPE.show();
        alert('Merci de charger le fichier' + intitule);

        return false;
        }
        i = i + 1;*/

    });
    alert(success);
    if (success == 0) {

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

the problem is when testing with ie :

```
 var n = $("input[type=File]").length;
        alert('number of files:' + n);
```

i get 0,chrom 4 (correct)

Comment: `$("input[type=File]").length` use this on alert to get the number of elements, and you don't have a `i++` which is the same as `i = i+1;` it's commented out, wudn't be surprise if you get zero on all browsers

Comment: Val,the problem is in the code above .each. not workin with ie 6.0

Comment: also try a lowercase file `$("input[type=file]").length` as oppose to File.

Comment: Yes it seems that the lowser case is the pb.now i have a problem with $(this).attr('style'); not working gain ie .thank you Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a lowercase file `$("input[type=file]").length` as oppose to File

**Reference from sitepoint.com**

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector

> Case Sensitivity The value specified in an attribute selector is case
>   sensitive if the attribute value in the markup language is case
>   sensitive. Thus, values for id and class attributes in HTML are case
>   sensitive, while values for lang and type attributes are not.
>
> XHTML, when served as XML, is always case sensitive; see Differences
>   Between HTML and XHTML for more on this.
>
> It’s not always easy to remember which HTML attributes are case
>   sensitive and which aren’t. It’s usually best to assume that
>   everything is case sensitive, but don’t rely on it!

**UPDATE SECOND QUESTION**

```
$("input[type=File]").each(function (i,n) {
    //$(n).attr('style');// note each. has a i,n on the function passed i, is for the increment, n is for the nth element,
    // sometimes, the each function when using $(this) may refer to every element selected, 
    // so i,n is the correct way to do it,
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/985bhaz6.aspx

please check this how to add attributes, I'm not familiar with it but I think/hope this would work

`writer.AddAttribute("data-style", "true");`

Comment: Val,please take a look at the the above code. $(this).attr('style') is not working  now :<input name="FondationTextBrowser0$DocFile" type="File" id="FondationTextBrowser0_DocFile" accept="pdf" class="case validate[custom[email]]" style="True" />

Comment: don't use style="true" remember style is [reserved for] a css attribute, use `data-style="true"`, then use `$(n).data('style')`//will return true;

Comment: data-style is not an attribute of input file,rigth?i want something that can help me filter my input file .that's the aim fo style="True","False"

Comment: according to your code yes, you'd have something like `<file type="file" data-style="true" />` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ read more on this `.data()`  and how it works, :)

Comment: the probelm is that i'm setting the attr in server side with c# when i do file.intellisence no data-style among them.how can i achieve that

Comment: sorry `<input type="file" data-style="true" />` don't know why i put `<file>` lool ignore the code above slightly, coz I cnt edit it :) :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot style certain attributes of a file input. It's a security risk the real experts tell me.
If you really need to change the look and feel, turn the opacity down to 0 on your file input and and style a text input and button to sit behind

Comment: JB,i'm just  looking for for server side attribute(asp.net c#) of file input that can help me filter the input file in jquery.can you suggest on.I've found style for the moment and i'm trying to filter the input file by its value rendered in the DOM